# Rails 5 + Boostrap 3 - Use full page width for sections on landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Technology: Rails 5.2.2, Bootstrap 3.3.7

In my `application.html.erb` layout, I have the following code:

```
<body>
  <div class="site-body">
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The content in my views has a fixed width due to being wrapped in Bootstrap's `container` class. I would like some colored sections on one of my pages to take up the full page width, but this is proving to be difficult because all of my view content is wrapped in the `container` class.

How can I customize just one of my views to have colored sections that will take up the full page width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new layout:

**layouts/full-width.html.erb**

```
<body>
  <div class="site-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And you can use it only on some pages:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'full-width', only: [:full_with_page]

  def full_with_page
    ....
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, Pablo! This worked very well. I found the documentation here thanks to your answer: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#specifying-layouts-for-controllers